# Can not find async after installation

Tags: node.js, npm

Today, I get strange thing that after i install async in global, nodejs reports it can not find the module.following is the workflow

1. install async

   npm install -g async
2. make sure async exists

   npm list -g async

get this output:

```
/usr/local/lib
├── async@0.2.9
└─┬ npm@1.3.21
  └─┬ request@2.30.0
    └─┬ form-data@0.1.2
      └── async@0.2.9
```

3.try to use it.

```
I create a simple js file which only contains one statement:
var async=require('async');
then execute the file via node, I get exception:
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'async'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/lxzhu/nodejs/asynctest/test.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: Why are you installing it globally?  Typically, the only things you install globally are packages where you're depending on an executable.

Comment: I would like to know why as well - regardless of best practice. I would assume it would work

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is because you are installing async globally.

`npm install async` will put create a directory called `node_modules`, and the `require` lookup algorithm will find it there.

Comment: so it never lookup global installation? I install it globally because I want to use it in two projects in my computer.

Comment: I know I can use this without -g option

Comment: iirc it won't look up your global installs when you are trying to use a module programmatically (ie via `require`).  Two different projects should have their own `package.json` files that each have async as a dependency.

Answer (score 6):

A global installation of an NPM doesn't always mean that the module can be shared for multiple projects. This is a pretty popular misconception. You can read [this blog post on nodejs.org](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) for more information, but generally speaking, global modules are used for command line tools and other system utilities, not for modules to be used in your code.

So, ideally, you would need the modules locally for each of your projects.

Answer (score 4):

async installed globally. For that we have to create and install modules of async.

**npm install async --save**

This command line add files in node_modules folder.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
npm uninstall async
npm install -g async
npm link async
```

Comment: This solves OP question without further noise. Big ups!

Answer (score 1):

One way of using globally installed modules in multiple projects is to use the `npm link` command

`npm link` will create a symlink of the globally installed package into your apps `node_modules` directory

Answer (score 0):

if dont Find Any Module like
Cannot find module 'sql' ,  Cannot find module 'nodemailer'
then use  npm install and module name which is can not found.
npm install async

Answer (score -1):

Finally, i get answer from http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html.

After install globally, i need to put its subdirectory to NODE_PATH to make it appears in node's search path.

Also, as the document said, It is suggested to store module locally and NODE_PATH is for version compatibility and we should not use it any more.